# How to add comment by apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to add a comment to a MS Word document by apache poi api.
I have done part of the work by using:

```
CTMarkupRange commentStart = paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeStart();
commentStart.setId(BigInteger.ZERO);
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("text");

CTMarkupRange commentEnd = paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeEnd();
commentEnd.setId(BigInteger.ZERO);

CTR ctr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewR();
CTMarkup ctMarkup = ctr.addNewCommentReference();
ctMarkup.setId(BigInteger.ZERO);
```

But I don't know how to link it to a real comment and I find nothing about it in api-document.
Do anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Office OpenXML Word document (`XWPF`) comments are in a special `CommentsDocument` `/word/comments.xml` in the *.docx ZIP archive. So at first we would need access to this document. But until now the `XWPFdocument` will only read that package part while creating. There is neither write access nor a possibility to create that package part.

So we must at first provide such a possibility to create the package part `/word/comments.xml` in the *.docx ZIP archive and to get write access to it.

In the following example the method `MyXWPFCommentsDocument createCommentsDocument(XWPFDocument document)` creates the package part `/word/comments.xml` and the relations to it. The class `MyXWPFCommentsDocument` is a wrapper class for that package part having write access to it.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import static org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;


public class CreateWordWithComments {

//a method for creating the CommentsDocument /word/comments.xml in the *.docx ZIP archive  
 private static MyXWPFCommentsDocument createCommentsDocument(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = document.getPackage();
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/comments.xml");
  PackagePart part = oPCPackage.createPart(partName, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml");
  MyXWPFCommentsDocument myXWPFCommentsDocument = new MyXWPFCommentsDocument(part);
 
  String rId = document.addRelation(null, XWPFRelation.COMMENT, myXWPFCommentsDocument).getRelationship().getId();

  return myXWPFCommentsDocument;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
 
  MyXWPFCommentsDocument myXWPFCommentsDocument = createCommentsDocument(document);
 
  CTComments comments = myXWPFCommentsDocument.getComments();
  CTComment ctComment;
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;

//first comment
  BigInteger cId = BigInteger.ZERO;

  ctComment = comments.addNewComment();
  ctComment.setAuthor("Axel Richter");
  ctComment.setInitials("AR");
  ctComment.setDate(new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US));
  ctComment.addNewP().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The first comment.");
  ctComment.setId(cId);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeStart().setId(cId);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph with the first comment.");

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeEnd().setId(cId);

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewR().addNewCommentReference().setId(cId);

//paragraph without comment
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph without comment.");

//second comment
  cId = cId.add(BigInteger.ONE);

  ctComment = comments.addNewComment();
  ctComment.setAuthor("Axel Richter");
  ctComment.setInitials("AR");
  ctComment.setDate(new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US));
  ctComment.addNewP().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The second comment.");
  ctComment.setId(cId);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeStart().setId(cId);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph with the second comment.");

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeEnd().setId(cId);

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewR().addNewCommentReference().setId(cId);

//write document
  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordWithComments.docx"));
  document.close();

 }

//a wrapper class for the CommentsDocument /word/comments.xml in the *.docx ZIP archive
 private static class MyXWPFCommentsDocument extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private CTComments comments;

  private MyXWPFCommentsDocument(PackagePart part) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   comments = CommentsDocument.Factory.newInstance().addNewComments();
  }

  private CTComments getComments() {
   return comments;
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions(DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS);
   xmlOptions.setSaveSyntheticDocumentElement(new QName(CTComments.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "comments"));
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   comments.save(out, xmlOptions);
   out.close();
  }

 }
}
```

---

This works for `apache poi 3.17`. Since `apache poi 4.0.0` the `ooxml` part is separated. So there must be:

```
...
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.*;
...
import static org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS;
...
```

Comment: It works perfectly and according to the solution, other part(commentsExtended.xml) of the *.docx ZIP archive could be created in the same way.Thank you for your answer sincerely