# How to add Classes for CommentsExtended.xml & CommentsExtensible.xml to POI 3.14

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi

I know that POI only supports XSD of 2007 but CommentsExtended.xml & CommentsExtensible.xml were introduced in 2012. But I need to add this functionality in POI & use it in our end. I have downloded XSD for both these files. But don't know where to get started. I know in general that POI uses Xmlbeans to generate low level classes for XSD Schemas. But don't know where to start & how to proceed. Any help will be really appreciable.

**First Attempt**

At first glance I tried adding creating CommentsExtended.xml package & add relation to it using OPCPackage API and was successful. But issue seems to be that a new relationship file like commentsExtended.xml.rels is created instead I want to add entry for commentsExtended.xml in already existing document.xml.rels.
**What am I doing wrong ? How to add realtion for commentsExtended file in the document.xml.rels itself ?** [Alex ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        createCommentsExtendedPackage();
}

private static void createCommentsExtendedPackage() throws Exception {

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/commentsExtended.xml");
        OPCPackage opcPackage = document.getPackage();
        PackagePart part = opcPackage.createPart(partName, ContentTypes.PLAIN_OLD_XML);
        OutputStream outputStream = part.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write("<test>A</test>".getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        
        //Creates commentsExtended.xml.rels file which is not needed.
        document.getPackagePart().addRelationship(partName, TargetMode.INTERNAL, PackageRelationshipTypes.CUSTOM_XML);
        
        //When trying to add relationShip in document getting NULL Pointer Exception
        POIXMLDocumentPart documentPart = new POIXMLDocumentPart(part);
        String rIdExtLink = "rId" + (document.getRelationParts().size()+1);
        document.addRelation(rIdExtLink, documentPart);
        
        // Save document
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        document.write(outStream);
        byte[] fileBytes = outStream.toByteArray();
        FileUtil.write("CommentsExtended.docx", fileBytes); //no i18n
    }
```

**Second Attempt:**
I am now able to add commentsExtended.xml relations in document.xml.rels using below code but now my value in commentsExtended.xml is being cleared upon save. How to retain value in commentsExtended.xml when value is set. **Any help is highly appreciable.**

```
private static void createCommentsExtendedPackage() throws Exception {

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        OPCPackage opcPackage = document.getPackage();
        
        PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/commentsExtended.xml");
        PackagePart part = opcPackage.createPart(partName, ContentTypes.PLAIN_OLD_XML);
        
        class CommentsExtendedRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
            private CommentsExtendedRelation() {
                super(  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.commentsExtended+xml",
                        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2011/relationships/commentsExtended",
                        "/word/commentsExtended.xml");
            }
        }
        
        //Adding relation in document.xml.rels
        POIXMLDocumentPart documentPart = new POIXMLDocumentPart(part);
        String rIdExtLink = "rId" + (document.getRelationParts().size()+1);
        document.addRelation(rIdExtLink, new CommentsExtendedRelation() , documentPart);            
                   
        OutputStream outputStream = part.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write("<test>A</test>".getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        
        // Create main document part
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        document.write(outStream);
        byte[] fileBytes = outStream.toByteArray();
        FileUtil.write("CommentsExtendedOld.docx", fileBytes); //no i18n
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI with known security issues? Why haven't you upgraded to the latest supported version?

Comment: The compiling the Java classes from the XSD is done using [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/). But that is only one thing. To be able to access `commentsExtended.xml` and `commentsExtensible.xml` there would must be classes in `XWPF` which are subclasses of [POIXMLDocumentPart](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocumentPart.html). Until now not even the default `comments.xml` is included in `XWPF` as such. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491860/how-to-add-comment-by-apache-poi/44511824#44511824.

Comment: It was pretty Old code base & it was holding up fine till now. Hence it remained unaltered for so long. [Gagravarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685641/gagravarr)

Comment: Oh Okk Thanks Alex. So if my understanding is fine compiling XSD using Xmlbeans will only generate low level CT Classes is this correct ? To get high level POI classes we need to write those classes from our end is that so ?  [Alex Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter)

Comment: @logesh ramasamy: Correct.

Comment: Okk thanks a lot [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter). I had CommentsExtended.xml & CommentsExtensible.xml XSD downloaded from this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-docx/d416013d-c112-44fa-8bef-7819b8898117).
Is this proper schemas for those ? Is there any other offical site to download schemas for MS Word features ?

Comment: Your schema is the correct one. But it refers to types of namespace="schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" too. So to be able to compile it using XMLBeans you will need all the schemas of Office Open XML published in [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/). Additional you might need schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml Schema too. So good luck!

Comment: Okk thanks a ton. Will try it out Alex.

Comment: At first glance I tried adding creating CommentsExtended.xml package & add relation to it using OPCPackage API and was successful. But issue seems to be that a new relationship file like commentsExtended.xml.rels is created instead I want to add entry for commentsExtended.xml in already existing document.xml.rels. What am I doint wronng ? How to achieve the same ?

Have added code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain the principle, I will try give a complete example which is as minimal as possible.

At first: Apache POI 3.14 is too old. My answer relies on current `apache poi 5.2.2`.

**Generating the `com.microsoft.schemas.office.word.x2012.wordml.*` classes from the `*.xsd` schema files using [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/)**

The `word12.xsd` can be got from the Microsoft source: [5.2 http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-docx/d416013d-c112-44fa-8bef-7819b8898117). But it has to be changed a little bit to be compilable.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:**w12**="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" ...>
```

Why is the `wordprocessingml/2006/` name space prefixed `w12`? That's irritating and should better be `w06`.

```
<xsd:import id="w12" namespace=**"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"** ...>
```

Why get the well known `wordprocessingml/2006/` name space additional imported as `w12`? That violates the given `targetNamespace`. It should be

```
<xsd:import id="w12" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" ...>
```

And since ECMA-376-Fifth-Edition the types `ST_OnOff` and `ST_String` are not more in `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main` namespace but in `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/sharedTypes`. So we need an additional namespace:

```
... xmlns:w06st="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/sharedTypes" ...
```

The complete `word12.xsd`:

```
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:w06="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:w06st="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/sharedTypes"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" blockDefault="#all" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" 
  targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml">
   <xsd:import id="w12" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" schemaLocation="word12.xsd"/>
   <xsd:element name="color" type="w06:CT_Color"/>
   <xsd:simpleType name="ST_SdtAppearance">
     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
       <xsd:enumeration value="boundingBox"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="tags"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="hidden"/>
     </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:element name="dataBinding" type="w06:CT_DataBinding"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_SdtAppearance">
     <xsd:attribute name="val" type="ST_SdtAppearance"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="appearance" type="CT_SdtAppearance"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_CommentsEx">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="commentEx" type="CT_CommentEx" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_CommentEx">
     <xsd:attribute name="paraId" type="w06:ST_LongHexNumber" use="required"/>
     <xsd:attribute name="paraIdParent" type="w06:ST_LongHexNumber" use="optional"/>
     <xsd:attribute name="done" type="w06st:ST_OnOff" use="optional"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="commentsEx" type="CT_CommentsEx"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_People">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="person" type="CT_Person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_PresenceInfo">
     <xsd:attribute name="providerId" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
     <xsd:attribute name="userId" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_Person">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="presenceInfo" type="CT_PresenceInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:attribute name="author" type="w06st:ST_String" use="required"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="people" type="CT_People"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_SdtRepeatedSection">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="sectionTitle" type="w06:CT_String" minOccurs="0"/>
       <xsd:element name="doNotAllowInsertDeleteSection" type="w06:CT_OnOff" minOccurs="0"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="ST_Guid">
     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
       <xsd:pattern value="\{[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}\}"/>
     </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_Guid">
     <xsd:attribute name="val" type="ST_Guid"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="repeatingSection" type="CT_SdtRepeatedSection"/>
   <xsd:element name="repeatingSectionItem" type="w06:CT_Empty"/>
   <xsd:element name="chartTrackingRefBased" type="w06:CT_OnOff"/>
   <xsd:element name="collapsed" type="w06:CT_OnOff"/>
   <xsd:element name="docId" type="CT_Guid"/>
   <xsd:element name="footnoteColumns" type="w06:CT_DecimalNumber"/>
   <xsd:element name="webExtensionLinked" type="w06:CT_OnOff"/>
   <xsd:element name="webExtensionCreated" type="w06:CT_OnOff"/>
   <xsd:attribute name="restartNumberingAfterBreak" type="w06st:ST_OnOff"/>
 </xsd:schema>
```

The `word12.xsd` refers to other types. So additional schemes needs to be accessible while compiling. Those can be got from [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/), Download part 4 and unpack `OfficeOpenXML-XMLSchema-Transitional.zip` of
`ECMA-376-Fifth-Edition-Part-4-Transitional-Migration-Features.zip` to a directory of your filesystem. I have done this to `./xsd/ooxml` (replace the `.` with your special location). Copy `word12.xsd` to this directory too.

Now we can do the compiling using `scomp`.

```
scomp -src ./xmlbeans/ooxml/src -out ./xmlbeans/ooxml/ooxml-schemas-word12-5.2.2.jar ./xsd/ooxml/word12.xsd ./xsd/ooxml/shared-commonSimpleTypes.xsd ./xsd/ooxml/shared-math.xsd
```

This compiles the three schema files `./xsd/ooxml/word12.xsd ./xsd/ooxml/shared-commonSimpleTypes.xsd ./xsd/ooxml/shared-math.xsd` and creates the JAR `./xmlbeans/ooxml/ooxml-schemas-word12-5.2.2.jar` and puts the `*.java` source files in `./xmlbeans/ooxml/src`.

After compiling you have the `ooxml-schemas-word12-5.2.2.jar` containing the new `com.microsoft.schemas.office.word.x2012.wordml.*` classes. If there are problems with compiling using XmlBeans, here is the resulting [ooxml-schemas-word12-5.2.2.jar](https://github.com/AxelRichter/apache-poi/tree/main/ooxml/word12). This must be in class path while compiling and running following code.

**Using the `com.microsoft.schemas.office.word.x2012.wordml.*` classes in `ooxml-schemas-word12-5.2.2.jar` to create a `XWPFDocument` having comments and using extended comment properties**

We know we need `/word/comments.xml` and `/word/commentsExtended.xml` in the `*.docx` ZIP archive. In `apache poi` `ooxml` this XML files are called document parts. There must be `XWPF` classes which extend `POIXMLDocumentPart` to handle those document parts. This classes need override `protected void commit()` to be able to save the content while `XWPFDocument.write`. Additional we need a method to create (add) this document parts to the `OPCPackage` (`ZipPackage`) of the `XWPFDocument`. The relation between the document parts and the `OPCPackage` is saved using a `POIXMLRelation`. So we need the `XWPFRelation.COMMENT`, which is already provided in `apache poi`, and additional `XWPFCommentsExRelation` which extends `POIXMLRelation`.

To be referable in `CTCommentsEx` the paragraphs in `CTComment` need attribute `paraId` from namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml`. We should avoid importing and compiling the [5.1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-docx/9704b59f-bc49-4618-ac66-41beb82a0d7f) only to be able to set this attribute. So we use `XmlCursor.insertAttributeWithValue` to add that attribute to `CTP` in `CTComment`. (Note: The above linked XSD seems not even to be the full schema for namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml`. At least there is no definition for atribute `paraId` in `CT_P`.)

Putting all this together we can have following code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.*;
import static org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;
import com.microsoft.schemas.office.word.x2012.wordml.*;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;


public class CreateWordWithCommentsAndCommentsEx {

//a method for creating the CommentsDocument /word/comments.xml in the *.docx ZIP archive  
 private static MyXWPFCommentsDocument createCommentsDocument(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = document.getPackage();
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/comments.xml");
  PackagePart part = oPCPackage.createPart(partName, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml");
  MyXWPFCommentsDocument myXWPFCommentsDocument = new MyXWPFCommentsDocument(part);
 
  String rId = document.addRelation(null, XWPFRelation.COMMENT, myXWPFCommentsDocument).getRelationship().getId();

  return myXWPFCommentsDocument;
 }
 
//a method for creating the CommentsExtendedDocument /word/commentsExtended.xml in the *.docx ZIP archive  
 private static MyXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument createCommentsExtendedDocument(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = document.getPackage();
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/commentsExtended.xml");
  PackagePart part = oPCPackage.createPart(partName, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.commentsExtended+xml");
  MyXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument myXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument = new MyXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument(part);
 
  String rId = document.addRelation(null, new XWPFCommentsExRelation(), myXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument).getRelationship().getId();

  return myXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
 
  MyXWPFCommentsDocument myXWPFCommentsDocument = createCommentsDocument(document);
  MyXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument myXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument = createCommentsExtendedDocument(document);
 
  CTComments comments = myXWPFCommentsDocument.getComments();
  CTCommentsEx commentsEx = myXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument.getCommentsEx();
  
  CTComment ctComment;
  CTCommentEx ctCommentEx;
  CTP ctP;
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  BigInteger cId;
  XmlCursor cursor;

//first comment
  cId = BigInteger.ZERO;
  ctComment = comments.addNewComment();
  ctComment.setAuthor("Axel Richter");
  ctComment.setInitials("AR");
  ctComment.setDate(new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US));
  ctP = ctComment.addNewP();
  cursor = ctP.newCursor();
  cursor.toNextToken();
  cursor.insertAttributeWithValue​(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml", "paraId"), "01020304");
  cursor.dispose();
  ctP.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The first comment.");
  ctComment.setId(cId);
  
  ctCommentEx = commentsEx.addNewCommentEx();
  ctCommentEx.setParaId(new byte[]{1,2,3,4});
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeStart().setId(cId);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph with the first comment.");

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeEnd().setId(cId);

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewR().addNewCommentReference().setId(cId);

//sub comment to first comment
  cId = cId.add(BigInteger.ONE);
  ctComment = comments.addNewComment();
  ctComment.setAuthor("Axel Richter");
  ctComment.setInitials("AR");
  ctComment.setDate(new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US));
  ctP = ctComment.addNewP();
  cursor = ctP.newCursor();
  cursor.toNextToken();
  cursor.insertAttributeWithValue​(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml", "paraId"), "01020305");
  cursor.dispose();
  ctP.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("Sub comment to the first comment.");
  ctComment.setId(cId);
  
  ctCommentEx = commentsEx.addNewCommentEx();
  ctCommentEx.setParaId(new byte[]{1,2,3,5});
  ctCommentEx.setParaIdParent(new byte[]{1,2,3,4});
  
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeStart().setId(cId);
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeEnd().setId(cId);
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewR().addNewCommentReference().setId(cId);

//paragraph without comment
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph without comment.");

//second comment
  cId = cId.add(BigInteger.ONE);

  ctComment = comments.addNewComment();
  ctComment.setAuthor("Axel Richter");
  ctComment.setInitials("AR");
  ctComment.setDate(new GregorianCalendar(Locale.US));
  ctComment.addNewP().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("The second comment.");
  ctComment.setId(cId);
  
 // ctCommentEx = commentsEx.addNewCommentEx();

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeStart().setId(cId);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph with the second comment.");

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewCommentRangeEnd().setId(cId);

  paragraph.getCTP().addNewR().addNewCommentReference().setId(cId);

//write document
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordWithComments.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }

//a wrapper class for the CommentsDocument /word/comments.xml in the *.docx ZIP archive
 private static class MyXWPFCommentsDocument extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private CTComments comments;

  private MyXWPFCommentsDocument(PackagePart part) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   comments = CommentsDocument.Factory.newInstance().addNewComments();
  }

  private CTComments getComments() {
   return comments;
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions(DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS);
   xmlOptions.setSaveSyntheticDocumentElement(new QName(CTComments.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "comments"));
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   comments.save(out, xmlOptions);
   out.close();
  }

 }
 
//a wrapper class for the CommentsExDocument /word/commentsExtended.xml in the *.docx ZIP archive
 private static class MyXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private CTCommentsEx commentsEx;

  private MyXWPFCommentsExtendedDocument(PackagePart part) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   commentsEx = CommentsExDocument.Factory.newInstance().addNewCommentsEx();
  }

  private CTCommentsEx getCommentsEx() {
   return commentsEx;
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions(DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS);
   xmlOptions.setSaveSyntheticDocumentElement(new QName(CTCommentsEx.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "commentsExtended"));
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   commentsEx.save(out, xmlOptions);
   out.close();
  }

 }
 
 //the XWPFRelation for /word/commentsExtended.xml
 private final static class XWPFCommentsExRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
  private XWPFCommentsExRelation() {
   super(
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.commentsExtended+xml", 
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2011/relationships/commentsExtended", 
    "/word/commentsExtended.xml");
  }
 }

}
```

This generates:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer [Alex Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter). Not only does it provide solution,you have also mentioned steps required to arrive at it in detail. I am trying to compile using xmlbeans myself but even after following steps in this [link](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/conInstallGuide.html), still while running scomp I am getting `scomp command not found exception in mac.` **Couldn't find any solution in XmlBeans FAQ & web as well.**

Comment: Reason for compiling schemas is that compiled jar is having latest xmlbeans 5.0.* packages structure which is not suitable or OLD POI 3.14 used in my end. Hence I am planning to use old XmlBeans 2.6 version to generate OOXMl schemas for this CommentsExtended XSD. CommentsExtended is of higher importance for me at the than moving to latest jars. Hence planning on going with old jars & hence compiling using XMlBeans 2.6 scomp which throws `scomp command not found exception in mac.` **Couldn't find any solution in XmlBeans FAQ & web as well.**

Comment: @logesh ramasamy: `scomp` is a tool from XMLBeans. It is located at `xmlbeans.../bin` directory. Alternatively you also could try call `java -cp ./xmlbeans-5.0.3/lib/* org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler -src ./xmlbeans/ooxml/src -out ./xmlbeans/ooxml/ooxml-schemas-word12-5.2.2.jar ./xsd/ooxml/word12.xsd ./xsd/ooxml/shared-commonSimpleTypes.xsd ./xsd/ooxml/shared-math.xsd`. That calls `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler` directly. But `xmlbeans.../lib/*` must be in class path.

Comment: @logesh ramasamy: "Hence I am planning to use old ...": Not a good idea. Old software will have vulnerabilities. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.14.

Comment: It seems to have some severe security loop holes. Then I will first mig to latest version at the earliest. Thanks a lot for pointing this out [Alex Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter)

Comment: [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) Upon checking shared ooxml-schemas-word12-5.2.2.jar & poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar, I could see there is some difference between methods in classes in both jar.Consider  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPrChange class, in poi jar, it has static factory methods along with comments where in compiled ooxml...jar it lacks static factory methods.So,using both jars with same pkg, would cause runtime exception when methods specific to 1 jar is depending on class loader. Why difference occurs & how to resolve it?

Comment: @logesh ramasamy: This answer was about how to auto-create the Java classes from XSD. The `ooxml-schemas-word12-5.2.2.jar` was never meant to ba a full replacement for the `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2.jar` (certainly not for `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar`, as the versions (5.2.2) needs to fit). If you would want this, then you would need to auto-create Java classes from all the XSDs. But this cannot be shown in an answer here as it is much too broad.

Comment: [Axel Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) Thanks for swift reply. I wasn't planning to use it as replacement but both in parallel. And my concern was just reg static methods mismatch btw jars. In schemas jar all factory methods seemed to moved to common DocumentFactory Class, but in poi-ooxml-5.0, static factory methods are inline is this diff arising because of compiling using diff version of xml beans (or) due to any other reason ? If so how to avoid it ?

Comment: Found reason for the same, it seems POI ooxml 5.0.0 was compiled using Older version of xmlbeans less than ver 5.0, latest poi ooxml 5.2.2 complied using xmlbeans 5.*.* seems to have same class structure as comments extended. Thanks [Axel Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter)